# REACT NATIVE: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.scroll = ref')

Tags: react-native, dependencies, expo, scrollview

I'm making an app in react native expo-cli v-45.0.0 and I'm using the library "[react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view)": "^0.9.5". I'm doing this to achieve the following situation: When I focus on a text input I want my screen to scroll to the input field, and the keyboard to doesn't lock the screen, additionally, I need the keyboard to disappear if I push anyplace of my screen. *The problem* is that sometimes, when I get into my screen with this implementation, it crashes and I get this message *undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this. scroll = ref')*.

this is my code.

```
import { 
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    TouchableWithoutFeedback,
    Keyboard 
  } from 'react-native';
//scroll keyboard
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'
<>
<KeyboardAwareScrollView  
 keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
 style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white'}}
 showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
 innerRef={ref => {
     this.scroll = ref
 }}
>
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
 ... my code
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
<Menu />
</>
```

[img related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpPVg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `innerRef={ref => { scrollRef.current = ref; }}`. I'm assuming that there's a `const scrollRef = useRef()` somewhere above that part of the code. Then to actually scroll you can use the following snippet before returning from your functional component.

```
const scrollToInput = useCallback((reactNode) => {
  scrollRef.current.props.scrollToFocusedInput(reactNode)
})
```

Make sure to change the `onFocus` prop to this too.

```
onFocus={e => scrollToInput(ReactNative.findNodeHandle(e.target))}
```